# error en el arranque del computador failed to start dnsmasq (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04

I turn on the computer and I get the following error (*see picture*)

Try this solution https://forum.manjaro.org/t/dnsmasq-not-starting-at-boot/86010 but without positive results.

I tried entering the shell recovery mode without success.

*Translated online, original follows :-*

prendo el computador y me aparece el siguiente error.

[image]

trate con esta solución https://forum.manjaro.org/t/dnsmasq-not-starting-at-boot/86010 pero sin resultados positivos.

probé entrando a la modalidad de recuperación de la shell sin tener éxito.

Comment: You haven't provided your OS/release details, but your url implies you're not even using Lubuntu.  Please provide OS/release details.

Comment: hola amigo ya hice las correcciones, estoy ocupando ubuntu en su versión 18.04.¿ alguna idea de como se puede solucionar?

Answer (score 0):

hello all people i save it problem.

well the url of post before it is run. post with more details.

Answer:

In /lib/systemd/system

open with command cli:
 vi dnsmasq.service 
i just have to add that command vi:
  a = add text
 :qw = save

You made these changes:
 After=network-online.target
 Wants=network-online.target

I also ran "systemctl enable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service".

and with save problem.